# python connected combinations of list items

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a list of values `[1,2,3,4,5,...]`, I want to return a list of all possible *connected* combinations using list comprehensions, numpy or whatever works.

By connected, i mean that pairs of items in the list should maintain their adjacencies in the combinations (not necessarily that integers with adjacent values are next to one another, although that would be OK).

To be clear, here is what i would like returned, in the case of a list `[1,2,3,4,5]`:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],
[1,2,3,4],
[2,3,4,5],
[1,2,3],
[2,3,4],
[3,4,5],
[1,2],
[2,3],
[3,4],
[4,5],
[1],
[2],
[3],
[4],
[5]]
```

And here are the types of items i do **not** want:

```
[[1,2,3,5],
[1,3,4,5],
...]
```

I have seen many posts about getting all possible combination in general, but i have not seen anyone pose the question about combinations with a connectedness constraint. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way with list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [lst[i:j] for j in range(len(lst)+1) for i in range(j)]
[[6], [6, 7], [7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8], [8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9], [9]]
```

Or if you value the order and if I guess it correctly from your example:

```
>>> [lst[i:i+leng] for leng in range(len(lst), 0, -1) for i in range(len(lst)-leng+1)]
[[6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

Or with `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> [lst[i:j] for i, j in combinations(range(len(lst)+1), 2)]
[[6], [6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7], [7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8], [8, 9], [9]]
```

Or even without any list comprehension at all (but now I'm getting silly :-)

```
>>> list(map(lst.__getitem__, starmap(slice, combinations(range(len(lst)+1), 2))))
[[6], [6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9], [7], [7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8], [8, 9], [9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import islice
def adj(l):
    ln = len(l)
    yield l
    for n in range(ln -1, 0, -1):
        yield from (list(islice(l, i, n + i)) for i in range(ln - n % ln+1))


l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(list(adj(l)))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

You can get a value at a time also without needing to store all the items in  memory:

```
def adj(l):
    ln = len(l)
    yield l
    for n in range(ln - 1, 0, -1):
        yield from (islice(l, i, n + i) for i in range(ln - n % ln+1))


l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for ele in adj(l):
    print(list(ele))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
```

Or call a function on each slice:

```
for ele in adj(l):
    print(sum(ele))
```

Output:

```
15
10
14
6
9
12
3
5
7
9
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: `def fl):` ?? i think you mean `def f(l):`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are a lot of ways to do this. I will suggest a simple function that may not be the more pythonic solution.

```
def c_list(A):
    B = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A) - i):
            B.append(A[j:j+i+1])
    return B

A = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]
B = c_list(A)
print B
```

This strategy could be used with list comprehension, if that's your thing:

```
C = [A[j:j+i+1] for i in range(len(A)) for j in range(len(A)-i)]
```